# How to output multiple value on excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using excel to perform some analysis.
I have a spreadsheet(Base) that contains the fields: ID Number Type Roles
and another spreadsheet (Results) that contains the fields: ID Number

How Can I add the type and roles on the spreadsheet(Results) when the ID and Number match the ID and Number on the spreadsheet(Base)?

I tried many different formula (vlook, textjoin) that does not work...

EDIT: Example

***Spreadsheet named Base***

| ID number | Roles |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Senior |
| 99 | Junior |

***Spreadsheet named Results***

| ID number | Roles | Techno | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Senior | Java | 3 days |
| 99 | Junior | Python | 2 days |

***Modification I want on the Spreadsheet  Base***

I would like to add when the ID number and roles match from the *Spreadsheet Base* match with the *spreadsheet Results*, than to include all the other columns (techno and time).

Comment: I believe you will have to provide example data, what you have here is not enough.

Comment: With the limited information given, I would guess that you need to create a helper column in Base so that you can lookup the contatenation of ID&Number.

Comment: Please share us with a simple and show the results that you want. Thanks ~

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0):

##### Formula

`FILTER` the **Techno** and **Time** columns of `Results` for a row where the **ID** and **Role** also both match the **ID** and **Role** of our test row in `BASE`.  Use `IFERROR` to handle errors when there is no match.

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(techno:time,(id=A2)*(roles=B2)),"")
```

| Name | Range |
| --- | --- |
| **id** | `Results!$A:$A` |
| **roles** | `Results!$B:$B` |
| **techno** | `Results!$C:$C` |
| **time** | `Results!$D:$D` |

<sub>**Sheet: `Base`**</sub>
[image]

<sub>**Sheet: `Results`**</sub>
[image]